# Insertshape draw FilledPolygon in wrong place - Matlab

Tags: matlab

Why does the insertshape function draw the FilledPolygon in the wrong place?

Code:

```
I = imread('coins.png');
BW = im2bw(I, graythresh(I));
[B,L] = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');
boundary = B{1};
boundary1 = reshape(boundary.',1,[])
newI = insertShape(I,'FilledPolygon',boundary1);
imshow(newI);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB there often is confusion about matrix indices `(i,j)`, where `i` is the row number, and coordinates `(x,y)`, where `x` is horizontal.

It is important to pay close attention to the documentation, to see if it refers to `i` and `j` or row and column, or it it refers to x and y.

In this case, [`bwboundaries`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html#bu1wval-1-B) returns

> Row and column coordinates of boundary pixels

and [`insertShape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertshape.html#btppvxj-1-position) expects x and y coordinates.

Thus, to put the output of the one into the other you need to swap the two columns of `B{1}`:

```matlab
I = imread('coins.png');
BW = im2bw(I, graythresh(I));
[B,L] = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');
boundary = B{1};
boundary = boundary(:,[2,1]);  % <<< swap columns
boundary1 = reshape(boundary.',1,[]);
newI = insertShape(I,'FilledPolygon',boundary1);
imshow(newI);
```